# mysql group by joined column too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join, group-by, entity-attribute-value

I have two tables `events` and `event_params`

the first table stores the events with these columns

```
events | CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `project` (`project`,`event`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2915335 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and second stores parameters for each event with these columns

```
event_params | CREATE TABLE `event_params` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(524) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `event_id` (`event_id`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20789391 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

now I want to get count of events those have various values on a specified parameter

I wrote this query for `campaign` parameter but this is too slow (15 secs to respond)

```
SELECT
    event_params.value as campaign,
    count(*) as count
FROM `events`
    left join event_params on event_params.event_id = events.id
                          and event_params.name = 'campaign'
WHERE events.project = 'foo'
GROUP by event_params.value
```

and here is the `EXPLAIN` query result:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key      | key_len | ref              | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events       | NULL       | ref  | project             | project  | 26      | const            |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | event_params | NULL       | ref  | name,event_id,value | event_id | 4       | events.events.id |    4 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

can i speed up this query ?

Comment: Please update the question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` structures for every table involved in the query and `EXPLAIN query` output we need this for performance questions..

Comment: Can you post up a fiddle? I don't see how a data set comprising just 4 rows can take any time at all !?!

Comment: @Strawberry no, I dont understand the explain query well but data set have 3 million events and 10 million event_params

Comment: Welcome to one of the inefficiencies of the EAV schema pattern.

Comment: How big are the tables?  What percent are 'foo'?  What percent are 'campaign'?

Comment: Do you get the 'correct' answer if you remove `LEFT`?

Comment: @RickJames data set have 3 million events and 10 million event_params .yes i get correct answer without `LEFT` , no differences

Comment: How many events are in `project` 'foo'?

Comment: @RickJames 2.8 million rows

Comment: @MohamadAliZeraatkar - that means it has to look at 2.8M rows.  That takes time.  My solution will also look at 2.8M rows, but it is more efficient because it won't bounce between the index and the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the following index on the `event_params` table, which might speed up the join:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON event_params (event_id, name, value);
```

The aggregation step probably can't be optimized much because the `COUNT` operation involves counting each record.

Comment: i have added this index but still the query execution is too slow

Comment: Then it is time to learn how to use `EXPLAIN` and check the query plan.

Comment: _Probably_ the combo `(event_id, name)` is unique.  In which case make that the `PRIMARY KEY`, tossing `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the "campaign value" into the main table, with a suitable length for `VARCHAR` and then

```
SELECT
    campaign,
    count(*) as count
FROM `events`
WHERE project = 'foo'
GROUP by campaign
```

And have

```
INDEX(project, campaign)
```

A bit of advice when tempted to use EAV:  Move the 'important' values into the main table; leave only the rarely used or rarely set 'values' in the other table.  Also (assuming there are no dups), have

```
PRIMARY KEY(event_id, name)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav